# Multiply and output sum mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Please tell me there is a code:

```
    <?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '*';
    $user = '*';
    $pass = '*';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM order_products WHERE id_order=1");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $summ = $row['price'] * $row['amount'];
    echo "
<tr> 
<td><img src='".$row['image']."' style='width:50px;border:2px solid #edc951;border-radius:5px;'></td>
<td>".$row['name']."</td>
<td>".$row['price']."</td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['amount']."' style='width:75px;'></td>
<td>".$summ."</td>
<td><input type='text' value='' style='width:75px;'></td>
<td><form action='/fun/deleteorder_products.php' method='post' style='display:inline-block;'>
    <a href='javascript:;' onclick='parentNode.submit();' style='text-decoration:none;color:#000;'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
    </a></form></td>
 </tr>";

}
?>
```

There is a `$summ` variable that counts the amount (quantity * price). How can I calculate the sum of all products? Thank.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, clarify the term 'sum of **all** products'. You might want the [$rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) property. Or 'total sum' could be generated procedural or within the query.

Comment: You are creating the connection to DB multiple times... in a loop. You only need one connection, remove the second `$pdo2 = new PDO(`

Comment: @Dharman There is not even any need for multiple queries at all. It can be done with joins as well.

Comment: Now with your edit you have entirely removed the `products` query. Based on your previous code you should try something like `SELECT * FROM order_products o INNER_JOIN products p USING(id) WHERE o.id_order=?` where `?` is the parameter for a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Instead of `*` the actually required colums should be listed explicitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable to keep track of the running total sum.

```
$total = 0:
while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    $summ = $row2['price'] * $row['amount'];
    $total += $summ;
    ...
}
```

Once all rows are fetched, variable `total` will contain the sum of all products.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин : you said you wanted the total of products, now you have it. What do *you* want to do with it ?

Comment: +10 This answers the question that was asked... how to get a total of $summ for all of the fetched rows. We could point out that $total is a running total in the loop, it has the value "so far". Once the loop is exited, then we have a value in `$total` that we can output. @ВладиславСамохин  GMB answered the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the formula inside of the SUM function

```
SELECT SUM(amount * price) AS total
```

Then you would just call to this:

```
$row2['total']
```

Comment: Will you please help to embed it in my code? Thank.